# unefficient code in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my view for some javascript variables. Any ideas that i can make it more efficient?

```
<% @sources.each_with_index do |source, index| %>

 ( <%= index %>, 1, <%= Entry.includes(:main_entries).where("classification_id =? and category_id =? and source_id =?", 1, 1, source.id).count %> )
 ( <%= index %>, 2, <%= Entry.includes(:main_entries).where("classification_id =? and category_id =? and source_id =?", 1, 2, source.id).count %> )

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can seem a bit dirty at first glance, but it's 1 query that counts it all in one go. Don't stick it into a view though. Make a class method and assign the variable in the controller.

```
Entry.find_by_sql(["SELECT classification_id, category_id, source_id, count(*) AS count_all FROM entries WHERE source_id IN (?) AND classification_id = 1 AND category_id IN (1, 2) GROUP BY classification_id, category_id, source_id", @sources.map(&:id)]);
```

What it will do is group entries by classification_id, category_id, source_id and count how many are there and store it as count_all (later loop through the results and call entry.count_all)

All you need to do now is loop through the results and output your javascript like you did before, but this time you won't be hitting the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be quicker if you create a class method or scope to select all the entries you want, and then iterate through the collection in the view.  Your current view code is making a database call on every line - you want to bundle these up into one call.  Without knowing a bit more about the relationship between the models it's not easy to be more precise